# How can I connect a Macbook 12-inch 2016 to a Macbook Pro 2010 in target disk mode?

Tags: macbook-pro

How can I connect a Macbook 12-inch 2016 to a Macbook Pro 2010 in target disk mode?
The Macbook has a USB-C port and the Macbook Pro 2010 has Firewire 800 and USB 2.0.

I couldn't find an adapter or cable for this.